# SQL Server : get all string occurences (tags) from nvarchar(max) variable containing a json string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a variable that contains a json string which is quite long. Datatype therefore is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Within this json string there are many of the same tags occurring multiple times. I am interested in all values AFTER the tag `IncidentName`.

It looks something like this within the JSON (but then nested in variable arrays that sometimes exist and sometimes don't):

```
"IncidentName":"Value1",
"IncidentName":"Value2",
"IncidentName":"Value3"
```

Could someone help me with building a loop/query that returns all of these values?

Comment: You need to extract the data from the JSON string first. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285223/accessing-json-array-in-sql-server-2016-using-json-value) for an example of how to do it.

Comment: I tried json sql but it is not reliable because the IncidentName's can be extremely nested within many variable nested arrays. That's why I'm trying to do it with regular sql and just treat it as a normal string.

Comment: SQL is not ideal for this sort of string manipulation. Are you able to pre-process the JSON or use a CLR function?

Comment: Or try [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41961/how-to-find-all-positions-of-a-string-within-another-string). There will be performance issues hence my previous comment.

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server you are using.  Different versions have very different support for JSON.

Comment: @gotqn no i need to retrieve the values, not replace them

Comment: Please edit your question adding: 1. tag for your SQL Server version 2. sample of input json 3. expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create SQL CLR function and using regex expression to match the data you need. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/1080354) you can find details of what is SQL CLR integration, examples of regex match function provided by Mircosoft and instructions how to create such functions.

So, having the above setup, you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "IncidentName":"Value1",
                    "IncidentName":"Value2",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "IncidentName":"Value3",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            },
        "IncidentName":"Value4"
        }
    }
}';

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] (@data, '(?i)(?<="IncidentName":")[^"]+(?=")');
```

[image]

The regex I am using is doing the following:

- (?i) - case insensitive search
- (?<="IncidentName":") - searching for this pattern, but this pattern is excluded from the final capture value (Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion)
- [^"]+ - matching every character different form `"`
- (?=") - using Zero-width positive lookahead assertion to ensure the match value is enclosed by `"`

Basically, you can use [this quick reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#backreference_constructs) to help you build regular expression that is going to work for your case.

The hard part is understanding what SQL CLR is and to implement the Microsoft's String Utility Pack. Then, you can solve issues, which are very difficult or not efficient to solve using plain T-SQL.