# Find Repeating word in a sql table entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named "EntityName" and "entityid".

```
 Entityid       EntityName
    1234        ABC inch EFG inch
    3456        inch* aaa inch vvv
```

Can any one please give me query to find these type  of repeating words.

Comment: You should already be familiar with [ask] - so you should know this question is considered low quality. Also, sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `SQL Server 2017` you can try the following query with `STRING_SPLIT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData(Entityid int,Situation varchar(100))

INSERT #TestData(Entityid,Situation)VALUES
(1234,'ABC inch EFG inch'),
(3456,'inch aaa inch vvv'),
(7890,'BBBB aaa inch vvv')

SELECT *
FROM #TestData d
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(d.Situation,' ') WHERE value<>N'' GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT(*)>1)

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

And you can show count:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData(Entityid int,Situation varchar(100))

INSERT #TestData(Entityid,Situation)VALUES
(1234,'ABC inch EFG inch'),
(3456,'inch aaa inch vvv aaa aaa'),
(7890,'BBBB aaa inch vvv')

SELECT
  *,
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(value,'*',cnt),', ')
    FROM
      (
        SELECT value,COUNT(*) cnt FROM STRING_SPLIT(d.Situation,' ') WHERE value<>N'' GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT(*)>1
      ) q
  ) DuplicatedWords
FROM #TestData d
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(d.Situation,' ') WHERE value<>N'' GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT(*)>1)

DROP TABLE #TestData
```

Result:

```
Entityid    Situation                    DuplicatedWords
1234        ABC inch EFG inch            inch*2
3456        inch aaa inch vvv aaa aaa    aaa*3, inch*2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(   
    [EntityID] INT
   ,[Situation] VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([EntityID], [Situation])
VALUES (1234, 'ABC inch EFG inch')
      ,(3456, 'inch aaa inch vvv')
      ,(1, 'only one inch');

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(12) = 'inch';

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
WHERE CHARINDEX(@Search, [Situation]) > 0
    AND CHARINDEX(@Search, STUFF([Situation], CHARINDEX(@Search, [Situation]), LEN(@Search), '')) > 0;
```

The idea is to check if there is a match of your word, then to replace it it and check if there is another match.

Of course, this is pretty simple matching. If you implement [SQL CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984086/1080354) function in order to get regex support in the context of T-SQL, you can add more complicated criteria.

Comment: This variant find only `inch`. What about other words - ABC, EFG? @Sruthi Suresh - or it don't need?

Comment: You can following the link in the answer to regex matches SQL CLR implementation. Using regex you can split a string to words and group by the match and count, if you need of course.

Comment: @Leran2002 my question was just an example of what i needed ,and in this scenario this is enough.your answer is perfect but not supporting sql server 2012