# Parse the data into separate individual columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `Physical-address` that I need to parse into it's own columns so that I need import it into separate address fields. The data in the column is like this:

Here are some examples:

1) 6453 W Church Dr, Summitville, CA, 46741, Brown

2) 2456 North Street, Greensboro, NC 27403

3) 5847 East Wood Dr, VA

4) 530 Alhambra Dr. Apt. A1 Anderson IN 46012

5) 1511 W 9th St, Anderson, IN, 46016

6) 2900 W 22nd St, Anderson, IN, 46013, Madison

7) Community Hospital, 1515 N Madison Ave, Anderson, IN, 46011

Result:

1) 46741

2) 27403

3) NULL

4) 46012

5) 46016

6) 46013

7) 46011

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It almost looks like "parse into it's _[sic]_ own columns so that I need import it into separate address fields" means extract _only_ a Zone Improvement Plan Code from an arbitrary string that may or may not contain a reasonable facsimile of a street address. A ZIP+4 Code will never be encountered. Does that sum it up? Do you have a _specific_ question or did you just want sympathy for your expressed "need"? What have you tried? What research have you done? Extracting any five-digit string found after passing over three spaces should suffice given your sample data.

Answer (score 4):

You might try this (thx, gotqn for the sample data!)

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('6453 W Church Dr, Summitville, CA, 46741, Brown')
      ,('2456 North Street, Greensboro, NC 27403')
      ,('5847 East Wood Dr, VA')
      ,('530 Alhambra Dr. Apt. A1 Anderson IN 46012')
      ,('1511 W 9th St, Anderson, IN, 46016')
      ,('2900 W 22nd St, Anderson, IN, 46013, Madison')
      ,('Community Hospital, 1515 N Madison Ave, Anderson, IN, 46011');
```

--The query will find all integers in the strings and return those in the intervall needed

```
SELECT ID,[value]
      ,fragment.value('text()[1]','int')
FROM @DataSource ds
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT [value] AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',',' '),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x[not(empty(. cast as xs:int?))]') B(fragment)
WHERE fragment.value('text()[1]','int') BETWEEN 10000 AND 99999;
```

### Some explanation:

the first `CROSS APPLY` will replace all commas to blanks and then split the string at all blanks (by transforming `a b c` to `<x>a</x><x>b</x><x>c</x>`).

The magic happens in the second `CROSS APPLY`:
`.nodes('/x[not(empty(. cast as xs:int?))]')` will return fragments, where the cast to `xs:int?` does not return empty. In other words: All values which are numbers.

As we return only numbers, we can savely use `int` in the `.value()`-method and can therefore simply check the interval using `BETWEEN`.

### UPDATE

Thx to HABO you might change this slightly:

```
SELECT ID,[value]
      ,fragment.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @DataSource ds
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT [value] AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',',' '),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x[not(empty(. cast as xs:int?))]') B(fragment)
WHERE LEN(fragment.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'))=5;
```

the idea is still the same: Find *pure numbers*. But the result is handled as string (not omiting leading zeros) and the filter is checking for a length of 5.

Comment: `/x[not(empty(. cast as xs:int?))]` - very clever and nice optimization indeed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using at least SQL Server 2012, the following is full working example. If you are using earlier version, replace the `IIF` with `CASE WHEN` and the `TRY_CONVERT` with other technique for checking if a string is a number (you can use pathindex to check if there are any not numeric characters, for example).

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('6453 W Church Dr, Summitville, CA, 46741, Brown')
      ,('2456 North Street, Greensboro, NC 27403')
      ,('5847 East Wood Dr, VA')
      ,('530 Alhambra Dr. Apt. A1 Anderson IN 46012')
      ,('1511 W 9th St, Anderson, IN, 46016')
      ,('2900 W 22nd St, Anderson, IN, 46013, Madison')
      ,('Community Hospital, 1515 N Madison Ave, Anderson, IN, 46011');

WITH DataSource ([value], [valueXML]) AS
(
    SELECT [value]  
          ,CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(REPLACE([value], ' ', ','),',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
    FROM @DataSource
), 
DataSourceFinal ([value], [number], [rank], [numbers_count]) AS
(
SELECT [value]  
      ,T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)')
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS.[value] ORDER BY T.c DESC)
      ,COUNT(T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)')) OVER (PARTITION BY [value])
FROM DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY DS.[valueXML].nodes('X') T(c)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)')) IS NOT NULL
    AND T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(128)') <> ''
)
SELECT [value]
      ,IIF([numbers_count] > 1, [number], NULL)
FROM DataSourceFinal
WHERE [rank] = 1;
```

[image]

The idea is simple - replace all empty strings with commas. Then split the newly created CSVs and look for the last number.

This can be solve really easy if you have [regex support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984086/1080354) in your T-SQL. For, example:

```
WITH DataSource ([value], [number], [rank], [numbers_count]) AS
(
    SELECT DS.[value]
          ,REVERSE(RM.[CaptureValue])
          ,RM.[MatchID]
          ,COUNT(RM.[MatchID]) OVER (PARTITION BY DS.[value])
    FROM @DataSource DS
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] (REVERSE([value]), '\d+') RM
)
SELECT [value]
      ,IIF([numbers_count] > 1, [number], NULL)
FROM DataSource
WHERE [rank] = 0;
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but this can be solved much easier. `XQuery` has its internal `TRY_CAST` (see my answer). It is called `cast as xs:int?`. Furthermore, I'd advise to encapsulate the string you use within the XML-split with `(SELECT TheString AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))`. This will implicitly escape all forbidden characters. Your solution would break, if one of the input values contains a `<, > or &` (or one of the many, many forbidden unicode characters...