# Select string between "\" and "." in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have the following table column named **file**  and it contains directories.
Sample data is:

```
C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML 

C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML
```

Note that I only want to get `6860_f11.xlxb` for #1 and `1191_f12.xlxb` for #2.

For #1, the directory only contains 1 folder `filedata` but for #2 it contains 2 folders `cloud\files`

Below is my code:

```
select  
    (SUBSTRING((file), 0, CHARINDEX ('.xlxb', (file)) + 4)) as xlsb_file 
from
    [Projects].[dbo].[ProjFiles]
```

Is there any way I could get the string after the folder and until the underscore after `.xlxb`?

Comment: If you reverse the string, then you will always be finding the first `/` and then use substring, then reverse it again.

Answer (score 1):

No CLR needed. No Regex required. The easiest and best performing way to solve this using [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). It's 2AM where I live so I'll make this quick.

**Note this query:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(150) = 'C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML';

SELECT RetPos = f.p, RetVal = e.s
FROM   (SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM samd.NGrams8k(@string,1) WHERE token = '\') AS f(p)
CROSS APPLY  (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,f.p,CHARINDEX('.',@string,f.p)-f.p+5)))  AS e(s);
```

**Results:**

```
RetPos RetVal
------ ---------------
16     1191_f12.xlxb
```

**Now Against a table:**

```
CREATE TABLE #yourtable ([file] VARCHAR(150));
INSERT INTO #yourtable
VALUES ('C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML'),
       ('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML');

SELECT *
FROM   #yourtable AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT newstring = e.s
  FROM   (SELECT MAX(position) FROM samd.NGrams8k(t.[file],1) WHERE token = '\') AS f(p)
  CROSS 
  APPLY  (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.[file],f.p+1,CHARINDEX('.',t.[file],f.p+1)-f.p+4)))  AS e(s)
) AS itvf_str_extract;
```

It's really that easy. The performance will beats the pants of any CLR/Regex Based solution too - so there's that.

On a side note: John Cappelletti's solution is excellent (as per usual). Under the hood it's very similar to my NGrams solution but not exactly; compare these two queries:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(150) = 'C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML';
DECLARE @Delimiter1 varchar(100) = '\', @Delimiter2 varchar(100) = '.';

-- Alan B
SELECT 
  RetSeq = 1,
  RetPos = f.p, 
  RetVal = e.s
FROM   (SELECT MAX(position)+1 FROM samd.NGrams8k(@string,1) WHERE token = '\') AS f(p)
CROSS 
APPLY  (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string,f.p,CHARINDEX('.',@string,f.p)-f.p+5)))  AS e(s);

-- John C
with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1;
```

Now the execution plans:

[image]

Comment: Impressive comparison and insight.   Gives me something to (re-)think about.  +1

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. This is one method

```
select substring(reverse(substring(reverse('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML'),1,charindex('\',reverse('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML'))-1)),1,13)
```

And if your filename is not always the same, you could do the same logic with `_`

This one will work with underscore - given that there is no other underscore  than xlxb_

```
select 
reverse(substring(reverse(reverse(substring(reverse('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML'),1,charindex('\',reverse('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML'))-1))),charindex('_',reverse('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML'))+1,len('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML')))
```

Comment: Is there any way we could do it, that will apply for the whole table column and not only with specific strings? Thanks

Comment: @mrya replace the string with your columnname

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks it will be better to implement SQL CLR function. Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984086/1080354) of how to create such. Having regex support, you can do things like the following:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] VARCHAR(256)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML')
      ,('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_Utils_RegexMatches] ([value], '[^\\]+\.xlxb');
```

[image]

Of course, you can create more complicate patterns to match using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If open to a Table Valued Function, consider the following.

Tired of extracting strings (left,right,charindex,patindex,etc.), I modified a parse function to accept **two non-like delimiters**. In this case `'\'` and `'.xlxb'`

Also being a TVF, it is easy to incorporate into a CROSS APPLY.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table ([file] varchar(150))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML')
,('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML')

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.[File],'\','.xlxb') B
```

**Returns**

```
file                                                RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML        1       13      6860_f11
C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML    1       16      1191_f12
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, starting with 2016, you may use STRING_SPLIT():

```
CREATE TABLE #FileTable (
   FullName varchar(150)
)
INSERT INTO #FileTable (FullName)
VALUES
    ('C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML'),
    ('C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML')

SELECT 
    f.FullName, 
    SUBSTRING(s.[value], 1, CHARINDEX('.xlxb', s.[value]) + LEN('xlxb')) AS FileName
FROM #FileTable f
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f.FullName, '\') s 
WHERE s.[value] LIKE '%.xlxb%'
```

Output:

```
FullName                                            FileName
C:\filedata\6860_f11.xlxb_3.30 test - 0.3 ML        6860_f11.xlxb
C:\cloud\files\1191_f12.xlxb_12.16 test - 0.3 ML    1191_f12.xlxb
```